# creating check box fields according to input type number value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this script
that calculate the number of days that in between the selected dates

UPDATE

is this code correct? how can i display the loop in my page?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#endDate").change(function () {
        var date1 = new Date($("#startDate").val());
        var date2 = new Date($("#endDate").val());
        console.log(date2);
        var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
        var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
      var dayes =  $('#dayes').val(diffDays);

        for( i=0;i<dayes; ++i ){
            var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
            checkbox.type = "checkbox";
            checkbox.name = "name";
            checkbox.value = "value";
            checkbox.id = "id";

            var label = document.createElement('label')
            label.htmlFor = "id";
            label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('text for label after checkbox'));

            container.appendChild(checkbox);
            container.appendChild(label);
        }


    });
});

  <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <lable for="prodayes " style="font-size: 16px ; text-align: center" class="form-control rounded ">Event Dates </lable>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <input  style="font-size: 16px ; text-align: center" class="form-control rounded " data-required="true" type="date"  name="from_date" id="startDate" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <lable for="prodayes " style="font-size: 16px ; text-align: center" class="form-control rounded ">TO </lable>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <input  style="font-size: 16px ; text-align: center" class="form-control rounded " data-required="true" type="date"  name="to_date" id="endDate" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <lable for="prodayes " style="font-size: 16px ; text-align: center" class="form-control rounded "> Total Days </lable>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <input type="number" disabled id="dayes" value="" style="font-size: 16px ; text-align: center" class="form-control rounded ">
                </div>
```

how can i create checkbox fields according to the script result?

Comment: What do you mean create checkbox fields? It's a little bit unclear what you're asking without an example. Could you show an example please?

Comment: i wish i had one. lest say the script result is 3. i wold like to create 3 check box field in a form. is that makes any sense?

Comment: So you want to create `x` checkboxes and add them to the form, where `x` is `diffDays`?

Comment: yes this is correct.

Comment: what's the relation to "php"?

Comment: sorry about that . i have removed the tag

Answer (score 3):

Just add this code to the end of your function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < diffDays; i++) {
    let elem = $('<div class="col-lg-2">');
    elem.append($('<input class="form-control rounded" type="checkbox">'));
    $("#dayes").insertBefore(elem);
}
```

This will insert `diffDays` checkboxes in the form, before `#dayes`. Your final code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#endDate").change(function() {
        var date1 = new Date($("#startDate").val());
        var date2 = new Date($("#endDate").val());
        console.log(date2);
        var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
        var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
        $("#dayes").val(diffDays);
            for (var i = 0; i < diffDays; i++) {
                let elem = $('<div class="col-lg-2">');
                elem.append($('<input class="form-control rounded" type="checkbox">'));
                $("#dayes").insertBefore(elem);
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: the code is not working,,, i try to console the diffDays but i get no result with this code

Comment: This code will automatically insert everything for you - and also, `diffDays` doesn't exist outside of the function because of `var`'s function scope.

Comment: i scope the diffdayes inside the script andi get the result but nothing is displayed on the page...

Comment: @JackBashford your for loop is not proper. check i think it's typo.

Comment: @CodeManiac and drorshalit I've fixed it now.

Comment: @JackBashford you forgot to fix top one

Comment: Oh yes sorry @CodeManiac, fixed it now.

Comment: what is happening now is that the input with the id=dayes is despairing and nothing is add... what am i doing wrong? i have copied the full code after the fix ..still the same problem...

Comment: My code adds `diffDays` number of inputs before `#dayes` - it should work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Make a loop and create like below

```
var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
checkbox.type = "checkbox";
checkbox.name = "name";
checkbox.value = "value";
checkbox.id = "id";

var label = document.createElement('label')
label.htmlFor = "id";
label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('text for label after checkbox'));

container.appendChild(checkbox);
container.appendChild(label);
```

Comment: can you please help me with the loop code and how can i display it?

Comment: store $('#dayes').val(diffDays); in a variable and loop it.